# Ask User For Extraction Zip and Extract File Advanced Installer

Tags: c#, advanced-installer

I want to ask the user for a path to a zip using a Public Property "[FILES_TO_EXTRACT]"

How do I setup advanced installer to ask the user for this path?

And then extract the contents to my choosing in advanced installer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [Browse for folder](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/qa-browse-for-folder.html) tutorial in their online user guide. Have a look, I think this is exactly what you are looking for.